# SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500 using ChromeDriver in Jenkins using Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing the below error on Jenkins scheduled execution. The execution was successfully done when I executed myself but when I set the schedule execution it show me the error.

Here the Image of the Error Message:

[image: Error Message Image]

Comment: The error is crystal clear `...this version of chromedriver only supports chrome version 115 Current browser version is 114...`

Comment: @ben ben try also this answer -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718696/i-am-getting-error-while-launching-chrome-browser-using-selenium-java-io-ioexcep/75719343#75719343

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

[image: 115]

...implies that *`SessionNotCreatedException`* was raised as [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to spawn a new *browsing context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=115.0*
- Where as you are using *chrome=114.0.5735.201*

So there is a clear mismatch between the major version of *chromedriver=115.0* and the *chrome=114.0.5735.201*

---

### Solution

Ensure that [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) is downgraded to [ChromeDriver v114.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.90/) level to match the *chrome=114.0.5735.201* and execute your test.

---

Further, if you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** or above you don't have to explicitly use [ChromeDriverManager().install()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) anymore as [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and your minimal code block can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

Option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Option)
driver.get("https://google.com/")
```

Comment: Hi @undetected Selenium, I am using Selenium 4.12.0 and execution takes place at local machine successfully. But as I setup CI/Cd with Jenkins which is at Azure and also use Kubernetes-docker containers I get error org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException in Console logs. Great if you can provide your help on this.

Comment: Just to add more information to my above comment - at Jenkins server chrome browser and chromedriver get downloaded in cache are of same version as happens at local machine.  INFO: Driver path: /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chromedriver

INFO: Browser path: /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/116.0.5845.96/chrome